# Find number of soldiers in a field given the following conditions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image]

I could not approach any logic To find number of soldiers in a field.Can anyone guide to solve the problem?

Comment: Just check each of the five possibilities to see if the remainders when dividing by 8, 15, 20, 9 and 13 are as specified. (Since you only have a few options to choose between, you don't even need to assume the remaining soldiers are Chinese. In fact, just checking for $N\equiv 1\pmod{20}$, which you can do in your head, eliminates all options except one).

Comment: Using process of elimination, 121 is the only number that has a remainder of 4 when divided by 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to divide each choice by the numbers given. 121 can be divided 8, 15, or 20 with a remainder of 1. 121 can be divided by 9 and 13 with a remainder of 4. The others do not work.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align*}
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x&\equiv 1 \pmod{8=2^3}\\
x&\equiv 1 \pmod{15=3\times 5}\\
x&\equiv 1 \pmod{20=2^2\times 5}\\
x&\equiv 4 \pmod{9=3^2}\\
x&\equiv 4 \pmod{13}
\end{array}\right\}\iff
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x&\equiv 1 \pmod{2^3}\\
x&\equiv 1 \pmod{5}\\
x&\equiv 4 \pmod{9}\\
x&\equiv 4\pmod{13}
\end{array}\right\}\\
\iff
x\equiv 121 \pmod{2^3\times 5\times 9\times 13 =4680}
\end{align*}
$$
by **Chinese Remainder Theorem**.

Comment: Once you use knowledge about the options, $x\equiv1\pmod{20}$ alone is enough to eliminate all the other options. So if you drag in Chinese remainders it can only be because you want to _ignore_ the given options -- and then you ought to use _all_ the information and reach the complete solution $x=121+4680k$ instead.